# How do I determine where the off-flavors of my brew are coming from?

Tags: flavor, off-flavor

Is there a website I can visit that will describe where different off-flavors come from? For instance, if the beer tastes malty, fruity, or bitter, where can I go to determine why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How To Brew by John Palmer contains a good summary of common off flavours:

http://www.howtobrew.com/section4/chapter21-2.html

Comment: Went through that list looking for inaccuracies.   Only found one:  "In beers which use pre-isomerized hop extract and very little flavoring hop additions, the beer will be fairly immune to damage from ultraviolet light."      ---  Uh, it's REDUCED hop extracts, not just pre-isomerized, that are resistent to photodegradation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing various articles about this on my blog.  Not as many posted yet as I'd like, but I also have a life and a job to attend to.  Look up the "Fishbone" diagram on my site for lots of good information about sources of quality issues in beer.

[Beer Sensory Science](http://beersensoryscience.wordpress.com/)